# Tkinter button with both left and right aligned text

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to create a button where the title is left aligned and then a value with units that is right aligned.

I need to be able to press it in ordre to open a new frame for changing the value.

I haven't been able to find a solution..

I have also tried to create two labels and then placing them inside the button but with no luck.

Any good solution is more than welcome.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvpFs.png)

Comment: I think the closest you're going to get in Tkinter is to give the Button text that consists of the title, several spaces, and then the value.  That's not going to look quite like you intended if the Button is forced to a width greater than its natural width.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, I was able to achieve the look by packing two `Frames` inside the button and using `pack_propagate` to allow you to dictate sizes, however as I suspected there were major issues with responsiveness and even the text randomly disappeared on the button when pressed.

Comment: Try formatting your button text like this `text = f"Message {n: >15}"`. This will insert 15 spaces between the message and value.

Comment: I don't want to use spaces.
The reason is that I will have 6 buttons below each other with some different text and values.
The text is likely to be above 500 different texts and the value the same.
It will take me yo much time to define how many spaces is needed.

Comment: I'd need a small code sample to know exactly how to solve your problem.